# Accessing Item in Style From Xml File

Tags: android, xml, styles

The background color is saved in the database according to the user's preference.The application will open according to the selected color of the background at each opening.I found out that the best way to do this by theme.There will be two themes in the Styles.xml file.

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="selectedBackgroundColor">#fff</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="selectedBackgroundColor">#000</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

in .java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if ( isUserSelectedBackground == true ) {
        setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

in activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewMain"
    android:background="?attr/selectedBackgroundColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:
    error: style attribute 'attr/selectedBackgroundColor (aka 
    com.myapp:attr/selectedBackgroundColor)' not found.

But this code not working. What should I do?

Comment: Try to use `R.style.DarkTheme` instead of `android.R.style.DarkTheme`

Comment: @sanoJ The real problem is that I can't access it from activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `attrs.xml` file in your `values` directory. Add `selectedBackgroundColor` attr to this file as given below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="customAttr">
        <attr name="selectedBackgroundColor" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```